# Using C# to request an AWS EC2 SpotInstance fails with Value () for parameter groupId is invalid

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ec2-spot-market

I am following the tutorial here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/how-to-spot-instances.html

And have created a C# Lambda function to test creating a spot instance. The function in question is:

```
public async static Task<SpotInstanceRequest> RequestSpotInstance(
      AmazonEC2Client ec2Client,
      string amiId,
      string securityGroupName,
      InstanceType instanceType,
      string spotPrice,
      int instanceCount)
{
    var request = new RequestSpotInstancesRequest();

    request.SpotPrice = spotPrice;
    request.InstanceCount = instanceCount;

    var launchSpecification = new LaunchSpecification();
    launchSpecification.ImageId = amiId;
    launchSpecification.InstanceType = instanceType;

    launchSpecification.SecurityGroups.Add(securityGroupName);

    request.LaunchSpecification = launchSpecification;

    var result = await ec2Client.RequestSpotInstancesAsync(request);
    return result.SpotInstanceRequests[0];
}
```

However the execution of the function fails with:

```
START RequestId: c64ea78d-d350-4f24-974c-09f31d16c5fd Version: $LATEST
One or more errors occurred. (Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty): AggregateException
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
```

I have verified I am referencing a security group that is valid and exists. I have tried the groupId, group name and 'Name' for the securityGroupId vale, but the same error occurs. Where am I going wrong here? I did some searches and they indicate this error can be caused by using the security group Id instaed of the group name, but i've tried all available references for the security group with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

From [LaunchSpecification Class | AWS SDK for .NET V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TLaunchSpecification.html), it appears that `SecurityGroups` is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>`.

The sample code might be wrong. Try creating the list first, then adding the security group to it.

Comment: Okay John, I'll try that out. From the sample code, it seemed that you could instantiate a string with the security group then add it like so: launchSpecification.SecurityGroups.Add(securityGroupName); (Additionally, am I right in assuming the valid value is the 'Name' of the security group? As opposed to the Id or the group name (which appear as distinctly different values in the EC2 console).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I tried List<string> sGroups = new List<string> { securityGroupName }; but the same error occurs irrespective of what identifier I use for the security group.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it appears the sample code is wrong. I did some further playing around, and discovered that you must reference the security group as follows:

```
    GroupIdentifier group = new GroupIdentifier { GroupName = "InSite App SG" };
    launchSpecification.AllSecurityGroups = new List<GroupIdentifier> { group };
```

This seems to be valid, and works. Not sure if it's relevant or not but i also specified the subnet for completeness. So I think the AWS sample code should be updated to reflect that rather than using a string for the group name, you should instantiate an instance of GroupIdentifier, add this to a List of GroupIdentifier, then pass that to the LaunchSpecification.

Comment: Interestingly, although the spot request now succeeds, the security group for the launched instance is 'default' - not the group I specified. The confusion continues.